# Adding lists of class objects into other lists of class objects in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, class

Adding lists of class objects into other lists of class objects in Python3

I have three classes templates in Python3:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, first_name, last_name, pronoun, discipline, grade):
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.pronoun = pronoun # he she
        self.discipline = discipline
        self.grade = grade # 0 to 100
        self.project_marks = [0] * MAX_PROJECTS

class Project:
    def __init__(self, proj_number, proj_name, proj_duedate, proj_pointvalue):
        self.proj_number = proj_number
        self.proj_name = proj_name
        self.proj_duedate = proj_duedate
        self.proj_pointvalue = proj_pointvalue

class Course:
    def __init__(self, class_name, class_number):
        self.class_name = class_name
        self.class_number = class_number
        self.students = []
        self.projects = []
```

I use a variation of the code below to fill in the class objects into an indexed list:
courses = []

```
file = open(COURSE_FILENAME, 'r')
data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
file.close()
print(data)

count = NUMBER_OF_COURSES

for i in range(0, count):
    courses.append(Course(data[i][0], data[i][1]))
```

I want to add my list of students[] into courses[] and also add my projects[] into those courses[].
I know I can do this in C++ but I want to do it in Python3...

```
for i in courses:
    for j in projects:
    courses[i].add_project(project[j])
```

```
    ~~~~~~~^^^
```

**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Project**

I have defined add_project into the Course class but I can't get there as this error gets me before reaching that code.
There is certainly a huge gap in my understanding of class objects and indexed lists of class objects!  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I think you're looking for `range(len(courses))` to iterate over the indices, same for `projects`.

Comment: Important terminology note, you **do not have a list of class objects**. You have a list of instances of the `Course` class. `Course` is a class object, which is used to create instances, e.g. `course = Course()`, in which case, `course` is an instance of the class

Comment: it should be pretty clear if you do `for i in courses: print(i)`... you seem to expect `i` to be an *index* like `0`, `1` etc. But it isn't `for x in somlist` iterates over *the items in the list*.

Comment: So you really just need `i.add_project(j)` although, you should give better names to `i` and `j` since they imply that these are indices. So maybe `for course in courses: for project in projects: course.add_project(project)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the problem was that this loop iterates over the **items**, not the indices:

```
for i in courses:
    ...
```

Here was my final implementation:

```
import csv
from pydoc import classname

NUMBER_OF_COURSES = 2
MAX_PROJECTS = 17
MAX_STUDENTS = 14
CLASS_272_2023 = 6
CLASS_672_2023 = 2 
COURSE_FILENAME = "courses.txt"
PROJECTS_FILENAME = "projects.txt"
UNDERGRADS_FILENAME = "undergrads.txt"
GRADS_FILENAME = "grads.txt"

class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, first_name, last_name, pronoun, discipline, grade = 0.0):
        # Run validation on the received arguments
        #assert student_id >= 0, f"Student ID must be greater than or equal to zero!"

        self.student_id = student_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.pronoun = pronoun # he she
        self.discipline = discipline
        self.grade = grade # 0 to 100
        self.project_marks = [0] * MAX_PROJECTS

    def set_project_marks(self, proj_number, marks):
        self.projects[proj_number-1] = marks

    def get_total_marks(self):
        return sum(self.project_marks)
    
    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade
    

class Project:
    def __init__(self, proj_number, proj_name, proj_duedate, proj_pointvalue):
        self.proj_number = proj_number
        self.proj_name = proj_name
        self.proj_duedate = proj_duedate
        self.proj_pointvalue = proj_pointvalue
    
    
class Course:
    def __init__(self, class_name, class_number):
        self.class_name = class_name
        self.class_number = class_number
        self.students = []
        self.projects = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students:
            self.students.append(student)
            return True
        return False
    
    # Read the CSV file of Student Class Instances into the array undergrads
    def add_undergrad_students(self):
        file = open(UNDERGRADS_FILENAME, 'r')
        data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
        file.close()

        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.students.append(Student(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5]))

    # Read the CSV file of Student Class Instances into the array grads
    def add_grad_students(self):
        file = open(GRADS_FILENAME, 'r')
        data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
        file.close()

        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.students.append(Student(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5]))
    
    def add_projects(self):
        # Read the CSV file of Project Class Instances into the array courses

        file = open(PROJECTS_FILENAME, 'r')
        data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
        file.close()

        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.projects.append(Project(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3]))
  
    def get_class_name(self):
        return self.class_name
    
    def get_average_grade(self):
        value = 0
        for student in self.students:
            value += student.get_grade()
        return value / len(self.students)
    
    def get_student_by_id(self, student_id):
        for student in self.students:
            if student.student_id == student_id:
                return student
            return None
     
    def get_student_by_first_name(self, first_name):
        for student in self.students:
            if student.first_name == first_name:
                return student
            return None        
            
    def get_student_by_last_name(self, last_name):
        for student in self.students:
            if student.last_name == last_name:
                return student
            return None

    def print_enrolement(self):
        for student in self.students:
            print(f"{student.pronoun} {student.first_name} {student.discipline} ")

    def print_projects(self):
        for project in self.projects:
            print(f"{project.proj_number} {project.proj_name} {project.proj_duedate} {project.proj_pointvalue}")


# Read the CSV file of Course Class Instances into the array courses

file = open(COURSE_FILENAME, 'r')
data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
file.close()

courses = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    courses.append(Course(data[i][0], data[i][1]))
    courses[i].add_projects()
    

for n in range(len(courses)):
    if int(courses[n].class_number) <= 300:
        courses[n].add_undergrad_students()
    if int(courses[n].class_number) >= 600:
        courses[n].add_grad_students()
    else:
        print("Class number does not match known parameters!")

print("------ENROLEMENT in each course")
for n in range(len(courses)):
    print(courses[n].get_class_name())
    courses[n].print_enrolement()
    print(f"----PROJECTS in {courses[n].class_number} ---------")
    courses[n].print_projects()
    print("\n\n")
 

# copywrite Tim Williamson 2023
```